# lack MOSQ_1.5 for mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto as one of my project tool. After i successfully compile (make binary) mosquitto via source code and try to run mosquitto_sub/pub, its shows that

```
./mosquitto_sub: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmosquitto.so.1: version `MOSQ_1.5' not found (required by ./mosquitto_sub)
```

while Mosquitto and Mosquitto_psswd is able is run without any problem. Besides, my mosquitto version is 1.5.

I have no idea about this problem.

Any Help appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have an earlier version of mosquitto installed and it's libraries are on the system path.

Make sure you have uninstalled any earlier versions of mosquitto installed on the machine.

Also make sure you have run `make install` as root in your build directory to copy the libraries to the correct locations

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue building on rpi model B+ using GNU make 4.2.1 and cc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0

Error reported: ./mosquitto_sub: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmosquitto.so.1: version `MOSQ_1.6' not found (required by ./mosquitto_sub)

Note: I left the existing distribution in place so that I could leverage off the systemd mosquitto.service that gets installed with the debian packages mosquitto and mosquitto-clients.

Resolution:

```
mkdir proj
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto.conf
cd mosquitto
# my build failed on master branch, so I picked a tag that worked for me
git checkout -b 1.6.9 tags/1.6.9 
make WITH_WEBSOCKETS=yes WITH_DOCS=yes WITH_SRV=yes
# overwrite the existing binaries
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
# verify that the newly installed binaries have overwritten the originals.
mosquitto --help|grep -w 'mosquitto version'
mosquitto_pub --help|grep -w 'mosquitto_pub version'
mosquitto_sub --help|grep -w 'mosquitto_sub version'
```